# On which IP the license should be issued by ANSYS authority?

Tags: networking, ip, license

my experience with networking is very poor. I was given a task to install Ansys Fluent at new computer at my university. The authorities provide national license and our university's public ip is authorized by Ansys national license server (ANLS) and each internal computer obtains licence automatically by connecting with the licence server via our public IP. However, our new computer was given by IT a static IP by which I can connect to it remotely through the SSH for instance, plus it has another IP for default gateway (which I supposed it was a public IP) and also it has some completely different IP when I check it through "what is my ip website". So, there are 3 different IPs what I can't understand and more importantly, which IP I should provide with the ANLS so they will be able to configure their license server to authorize our new computer.

Answer (score 0):

When connecting from inside the university network, the IP should be the public
one that you see on the Internet with any "what is my ip" website.

The default gateway is probably the university's router, only applicable internally.

The static IP for SSH is most likely for a special-purpose, and is usually used
for getting inside or outside of the university network.